# Mongoose aggregate returning all data from lookup instead of linked data or inner join type

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections: Classes and Files.

Given the following code:

```
Classes.aggregate([      
        {$match: {  'owner': req.headers.account_id }},
        {$lookup: {
          from: "files",
          localField: "classId",
          foreignField: "_id.str",
          as: "files"
        }},

    ]).exec(function (err, classes) {
      //console.log(classes)
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      } else {
        if (typeof classes !== "undefined" && classes) {
          res.send(classes);
          res.end();
        } else {
          return res.send({
            success: false,
            message: 'there was an error fetching classes.'
          });
        }
      }

    });
  })
```

I need to return only where classId in collection files is equal to _id in collection classes. Right now it is returning all file without that filter of equality. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I wound up doing this temporarily. Is this really the only way?

```
router.route('/:class_id*?')
  // get the account with that id (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/accounts/:account_id)
  .get(function (req, res) {

    //console.log('ATTEMPTING TO FIND BY ID!', req);
    Classes.find({
      'owner': req.headers.account_id,
      deleted: {
        $ne: true
      }
    }
      //removed because not doing 'innder join'
      /*Classes.aggregate([      
          {$match: {  'owner': req.headers.account_id }},
          {$lookup: {
            from: "files",
            localField: "_id.str",
            foreignField: "classId.str",
            as: "files"
          }}],*/


    ).exec(function (err, classes) {
      var classesMap = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(classes));
      if (classes.length > 0) {
        var classIds = [];
        classes.map(function (obj) {
          classIds.push(obj._id);
        })

        //get all of' the files for all of the classes that camae back..
        Files.find({ classId: { $in: classIds } }).exec(function (err, files) {
          var temp = [];
          var array = classesMap.map(function (obj, index) {
            obj.files = files.filter(file => file.classId.toString() == classes[index]._id.toString());
            temp.push(obj);
          })

          res.send(temp).end();

        })
      }


    });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with your first approach -- your other one looks scary.

Unless I am misunderstanding something, I believe you just need to add an additional stage to filter classes with no files.

> Right now it is returning all files without that filter of equality.

It is possibly not working because you need to flip the values for `localField` and `foreignField`.

It should return documents with an additional `files` array. Those documents that have files mean that they were joined by `class._id` and `file.classId`.

```
Classes.aggregate([      
    {
        $match: { 
            owner: req.headers.account_id
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'files',
            localField: '_id', // field from the Classes documents
            foreignField: 'classId', // field from the Files documents
            as: 'files'
        }
    },
    // at this point, each document may (or may not) have an array of files
    // so filter out the classes that have no files
    {
        $match: { 
            files: { $exists: true, $ne: [] }
        }
    }
]).exec(function (err, classes) {
    console.log(classes)
    if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
    }
    if (typeof classes !== 'undefined' && classes) {
        return res.send(classes);
    }
    res.send({ success: false, message: 'there was an error fetching classes.' });
})
```